# Can't create QOpenGLTexture

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opengl-es, qt5

I have a problem with my textures. I want to import texture from `uchar*` but if i use this method i see nothing on my screen. if i import texture from `QImage` it is work.Whats wrong with my program?

This code work.

```
QImage image = LoadTextureFromFile(MP, c->file);
mp->m_textures.m_textures.last()->setData(image);
mp->m_textures.m_textures.last()->setMinMagFilters(QOpenGLTexture::Linear, QOpenGLTexture::Linear);
```

This code dont work..

```
QImage image = LoadTextureFromFile(MP, c->file);
mp->m_textures.m_textures.last()->setSize(c->width, c->height);
mp->m_textures.m_textures.last()->setFormat(QOpenGLTexture::RGBA8_UNorm);
mp->m_textures.m_textures.last()->allocateStorage(QOpenGLTexture::RGBA, QOpenGLTexture::UInt8);
mp->m_textures.m_textures.last()->setData(QOpenGLTexture::RGBA, QOpenGLTexture::UInt8, image.bits());
mp->m_textures.m_textures.last()->generateMipMaps();
mp->m_textures.m_textures.last()->setMinMagFilters(QOpenGLTexture::Linear, QOpenGLTexture::Linear);
```

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Is your image file power of two sizes?

Comment: @starmole i write this code from example of native opengl like this `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);` this code work with array of data with width and height - 2 sizes. file with texture is png picture 128x128.

Comment: In the second example try converting the `QImage` format to `QImage::Format_RGBA8888` before using it in the call to `QOpenGLTexture::setData`.  That *appears* to be what the [`QOpenGLTexture::setData(const QImage &image)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopengltexture.html#setData-9) overload does.

Comment: @G.M. this method does not help me...